# Bootstrap 3 offset ignores sizes

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have an offset set for a medium sized screen but the offset still occurs when the screen is in large. Here is a snippet of my html, how can I solve this issue?

```
<div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-12">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-3 col-md-offset-3"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In bootstrap, device-size-specific classes affect the size of the class **and all the higher sizes**, unless overridden. So, of course, `col-md-offset-3` will be present in large screens as well. You can "override" this class for large screens with `col-lg-offset-0`.

```
<div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-12">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-3 col-md-offset-3 col-lg-offset-0"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

From the [docs](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid):

> Grid classes apply to devices with screen widths greater than or equal
>   to the breakpoint sizes, and override grid classes targeted at smaller
>   devices. Therefore, applying any `.col-md-` class to an element will not
>   only affect its styling on medium devices but also on large devices if
>   a `.col-lg-` class is not present.

Comment: wow I always thought it was the breaking point and smaller, thank you.

Comment: Bootstrap is mobile-first, so it's mobile-and-up, not desktop-and-down.